# Clustering similar values in a matrix

Tags: language-agnostic, matrix, analysis, similarity

I have an interesting problem and I'm sure there is an elegant algorithm with which to solve the solution but I'm having trouble describing is succinctly which would help finding such an algorithm.

I have a symmetric matrix of comparison values e.g:

```
-104.2732   -180.3972   -130.6969   -160.8333   -141.5499   -139.2758   -144.7697   -114.0545   -117.6409   -140.1391
-180.3972   -93.05421   -171.618    -162.0157   -156.8562   -156.3221   -159.9527   -163.2649   -170.127    -153.2709
-130.6969   -171.618    -101.1591   -154.4978   -143.6272   -116.3477   -137.2391   -125.5645   -128.9505   -131.6046
-160.8333   -162.0157   -154.4978   -96.96312   -122.7894   -141.5103   -127.7861   -149.6883   -153.0445   -130.2555
-141.5499   -156.8562   -143.6272   -122.7894   -101.7487   -141.451    -123.9087   -138.7041   -139.2517   -125.3494
-139.2758   -156.3221   -116.3477   -141.5103   -141.451    -99.99486   -134.6553   -132.7735   -138.7249   -134.1319
-144.7697   -159.9527   -137.2391   -127.7861   -123.9087   -134.6553   -100.0683   -141.3492   -138.0292   -120.5331
-114.0545   -163.2649   -125.5645   -149.6883   -138.7041   -132.7735   -141.3492   -106.8555   -115.58 -139.3355
-117.6409   -170.127    -128.9505   -153.0445   -139.2517   -138.7249   -138.0292   -115.58 -104.9484   -140.4741
-140.1391   -153.2709   -131.6046   -130.2555   -125.3494   -134.1319   -120.5331   -139.3355   -140.4741   -101.3919
```

The diagonal will always show the maximum score (as it is a self-to-self comparison).  However I know that of these values some of them represent the same item.  Taking a quick look at the matrix I can see (and have confirmed manually) that items 0, 7 & 8 as well as 2 & 5 and 3, 4, 6 & 9 all identify the same item.

Now what I'd like to do is find an elegant solution as to how I would cluster these together to produce me 4 clusters.

Does anyone know of such an algorithm?  Any help would be much appreciated as I seem so close to a solution to my problem but am tripping at this one last stumbling block :(

Cheers!